# Splitting a text into equal sized parts

Tags: r, word-count

as I am new to R and semi new to programming in general, I hope someone can help me. I have a matrix in which there is text body in column 2. For further analysis I want to split that text into multiple parts of equal length, i.e. the same number of words (2 for the beginning). I also want to process those new parts further, so I would like them to be integrated into the existing matrix yet new columns.

Now I have found the **split** function and was wondering if I can solve my problem with it?
[Split function](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/NCmisc/html/file.split.html)

Also, can I implement a dynamic word counter ("count every word in a message until value is greater than...")?

Any tips on how to progress would be greatly appreciated. Thank you already in advance.

EDIT 2: 
My code so far looks like this:

```
library(tm)
library(NLP)

TestMatrix2 = matrix(c("1", "2","The masked shrike (Lanius nubicus) is a bird in the shrike family, Laniidae. It breeds in southeastern","The throat, neck sides and underparts are white, with orange flanks and breast","17","13"),2,3)
colnames(TestMatrix2) = c("index","news body", "word count")

Test2 <- data.frame(strsplit(TestMatrix2[[1,1]], " "),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 NewsPartitioning <- function(NumberOfParts = 2, NewsIndicator= 1){
 MaxWords = TestMatrix2[NewsIndicator,3]
 CritValue = TestMatrix2[NewsIndicator,3]/NumberOfParts
 as.integer(CritValue)
new = list()
colnames(Test2) = c("Words")

for (i in 1:CritValue){new = c(new,Test2$Words[i])}
 new = unlist(new)
 TestMatrix[NewsIndicator,3+NumberOfParts] = paste(new, collapse = " ")

for (i in CritValue+1:MaxWords){new = c(new,Test2$Words[i])}
 new = unlist(new)
 TestMatrix[Nachricht,3+NumberOfParts] = paste(new, collapse = " ")
}
```

At the moment, I am being given the error message "new columns would leave holes after existing columns".

I guess the procedure is neither efficient nor very elegant. Any thoughts or help?

Best regards
Basti

Comment: hi, why don't you try to add an example of both the input and the output?

Comment: Hey @Pasqui, I edited the original question. I hope it is easier to understand now. Thx already

Comment: Please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)